# How to differentiate Bot to user AND user to Bot messages using middleware in bot builder sdk v4?

Tags: node.js, botframework, middleware, azure-cognitive-services

I have implemented a middleware in sdk V4 Bot to intercept each message between bot & user and log that custom mongo Db. I am trying to implement similar concept for Bot built using SDK v4. Looks like I can use following piece of code to add a middleware but, not sure how to differentiate message between bot to user & user to bot.

V3 bot code

```
bot.use({
    botbuilder: function (session, next) {
        logUserConversation(session)
        next()
    },
    send: function (event, next) {
        logBotsConversation(event)
        next()
    }
})
```

V4 bot code for Middleware

```
botAdapter.use(async (turnContext, next) => {
    // How to find which messages/activity object is from user to bot

    await next();
    // How to find which messages/activity object is from bot to user.
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the function that you pass to `.use` represents a piece of middleware that can do pre and post processing of an *incoming* activity. You access the "current" activity from the turn context via the `turnContext.Activity` property. Those activities can either be sent from the user or from some other system that sends them via the DirectLine API to the bot (assuming you're using the Bot Framework Service).

*Outgoing* activities, that is activities that are sent from the bot in response to the incoming activities, can also be intercepted by middleware, but the middleware needs to involve itself in the sending of those activities more explicitly. It does this by registering a handler with the turn context using the `onSendActivities` API.

This all comes together to look a little something like this:

```js
botAdapter.use(async (turnContext, next) => {
    // pre-processing of the current incoming activity
    console.log(`Processing activity ${turnContext.activity.id} starting... `);

    // hook up a handler to process any outgoing activities sent during this turn
    turnContext.onSendActivities(async (sendContext, activities, nextSend) => {
       // pre-processing of outgoing activities

       await nextSend();       

       // post-processing outgoing activities
    });

    await next();

    // post-processing of the current incoming activity 
    console.log(`Processing activity ${turnContext.activity.id} finishing. `);    

});
```

The one thing to note is that outgoing activity handlers can be invoked `0..*` times as they are basically triggered by downstream logic calling `turnContext.sendActivit[y|ies]`. So if, during the turn, there are multiple activities sent, your handler will be invoked for each batch.

Comment: I am not able to capture activities going from Bot to User using above logic. 

turnContext.activity.text . - gives text that user typed.

Comment: Inside the closure passed to `onSendActivities` you need to make sure you're using the `sendContext` variable, _not_ `turnContext`.

Comment: I did that and it didn't work. Ex-I sent text 'help' to bot & after first console.log from above code I did ( turnContext.activity.text ) which resulted into ''help". Sounds good.
when Bots reply was ready which is 'I can help you get your task done.' to capture this inside turnContext.onSendActivities(.....) I did sendContext.activity.text which again resulted into 'help' which is what user had typed.

Comment: It looks like activities object has data that's from Bot to User.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're looking at the `turnContext.activity`... that's _always_ the incoming activity. In the scope of the `onSendActivities` the outgoing activities are in the `activities` parameter which is an array of `Activity`.

Comment: I had to do a little modification as below in order make it work. "return await nextSend();"

Comment: I tried following this. But for some reason, each activity is being processed twice !! Any idea what might have gone wrong.