# How to log transcripts of both User and bot

Tags: botframework

I've enabled transcript logging by

```
Use(new TranscriptLoggerMiddleware(new AzureBlobTranscriptStore(settings.BlobStorage.ConnectionString, settings.BlobStorage.Container)));
```

It only stores User messages though. How do I make it log bot answers too?
Is there a way to convert a bunch of JSON files into readable line-by line transcript like one user sees in the webchat?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this would make a difference, but this is how I'm setup. Fundamentally, I'd say it's not really different than your setup. Are there any other settings, configurations or middleware you are passing thru that you have enabled and might be interfering?

```js
const transcriptStore = new AzureBlobTranscriptStore({
    storageAccountOrConnectionString: process.env.blobStorageConnectionString,
    containerName: process.env.blobStorageContainer
});

const transcriptMiddleware = new TranscriptLoggerMiddleware(transcriptStore);

const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter(adapterSettings)
    .use(transcriptMiddleware);
```

Hope of help!

Comment: But this does not log the outgoing messages

Answer (score 0):

I  learned from this answer to create my own middleware that stores the incoming and outgoing activities in the database. I store them in Ms SQL, then I use sendConversationHistory to send the stored activities to the webchat.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54228225/10531724
If you need more clarification please let me know.