# Botframework catching outgoing and incoming activities

Tags: botframework

I want to catch some state variables of the conversation using the next code in the MyBot : ActivityHandler class:

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   var message = turnContext.Activity.Text;
}
```

But this is happening only when the user makes an action not when the bot sends any message (I´m aware turncontext only process inbound activities). I need to catch both outcoming and incoming activities in order to access something like the turncontext... Which method should I use?

I´ve seen in the emulator right pane and they catch all messages, how do they do that?

This event depend of the channel?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need middleware for that: [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Some code to get you started is in the accepted answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54227991/how-to-differentiate-bot-to-user-and-user-to-bot-messages-using-middleware-in-bo)

Comment: Tx Hessel, I believe the answer is in that post but since I´m new in this bot development world I´m struggling figuring out how to implement the solution. I mean I haven´t found a clear example of this.... How to use TranscriptLoggerMiddleware C#?... Again Tx..

Comment: @Tito, refer to https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1380 and https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1380#issuecomment-515283270 on getting started with implementing TranscriptLoggerMiddleware